# passing an argument in javascript function

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

i have a button with id Button1
on page load function i m trying to call javascript function like this

```
int l = files.Length;
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", " alertMe(l);");
```

where files.length is some integer value,now i m trying to pass this value in alertMe function
can anyone tell me is it a write way to pass the value if yes how can i retrieve it in alertMe function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int l = files.Length;
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", " alertMe(" + l + ");");
```

Comment: thnx but how can i retrieve it in the alertMe  function

Comment: Fabian Vilers' response will help you with that part

Comment: Still, I think it would be better to use the `Button.OnClientClick` property. See my answer for an example.

Comment: That's definitely a valid point, i upvoted you for that. I just wanted to show with the least amount of modification, what sumit was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
function alertMe(length)
{
    alert("you passed a length of: " + length);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sample, the value passed to the javascript function is always 1. Also, you might want to use the [`Button.OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property instead, as this ensures that ASP.NET's own button handling code is left intact. Your C#  code should probably look something like this:

```
int fileCount = files.Length;
Button1.OnClientClick = "alertMe(" + fileCount + ");"
```

In the javascript, make sure you declare the formal parameter in the function signature:

```
function alertMe(fileCount)
{
    alert(fileCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
int l = files.Length;
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", " alertMe(" + l.ToString() + ");");
```